# I want to alter bin ranges format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame and i am creating bins with pd.qcut as following:

```
us_counties['bins'] = pd.qcut(us_counties['economic connectedness'], q=10,precision=2)
```

The bins are:

```
us_counties.bins.cat.categories
IntervalIndex([(0.27999999999999997, 0.58], (0.58, 0.67], (0.67, 0.72], (0.72, 0.76], (0.76, 0.81], (0.81, 0.85], (0.85, 0.9], (0.9, 0.97], (0.97, 1.06], (1.06, 1.36]], dtype='interval[float64, right]')
```

I want to change their format so the first bin is <0.58, the medium ones 0.67-0.72 and the last one >1.06.

I managed to make the format of the medium ones with the following command:

```
us_counties.bins.cat.categories = [f'{i.left} - {i.right}' for i in us_counties.bins.cat.categories]
```

How can I change the first and last one, so that I end with bins that look like:

```
['<0.58','0.58 - 0.67',....,'0.97 - 1.06','>1.06']
```

Comment: I'm unclear: are you looking to make only 3 bins - first, medium, last? Or are you trying to change endpoint inclusion like 0.58] --> 0.58)?

Comment: I want to produce n amount of bins from qcut and the alter the formatting of the bins 'labels' for the looks of the graph only.

Comment: If you just want to change the labels, pass in an array of labels that you want: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: But it looks like you want to create the labels afterwards based on the bins that are created. If you got the code `{i.left}-{i.right}` to work for the middle bins, what does that do to your first and last bins?

Comment: The array of labels is a static way, I am looking for something dynamic. The {i.left} - {i.right} makes all the labels as 'left_bound - right_bound'.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. But what happens with 'left_bound - right_bound' on the first bin?

Comment: These are the categories created:
```Index(['0.27999999999999997 - 0.58', '0.58 - 0.67', '0.67 - 0.72',
       '0.72 - 0.76', '0.76 - 0.81', '0.81 - 0.85', '0.85 - 0.9', '0.9 - 0.97',
       '0.97 - 1.06', '1.06 - 1.36'],
      dtype='object')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
mybinlabels = [f'{i.left} - {i.right}' for i in us_counties.bins.cat.categories]
mybinlabels[0] = ["<"+str(i.right) for i in [us_counties.bins.cat.categories[0]]]
mybinlabels[-1] = [">"+str(i.left) for i in [us_counties.bins.cat.categories[-1]]]
us_counties.bins.cat.categories = mybinlabels
```

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it! =D And thanks for the accepted answer too!

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do it with `qcut` on the reason that `qcut` distributes data points into equal-sized buckets. In your way, this equality will not be maintained. For example, 0.58 is inclusive by `qcut` but you want it to be exclusive. So, what you can do is create a function and another column, and assign a bin to each row using `apply` function. Then, based on the new column, you can do whatever you wish to do in the next round. I may suggest this if I understand your case correctly.

Comment: I want to produce the equal-sized buckets from the qcut dynamically and then alter the formatting of the labeling of the buckets